# Scala multiple imports doesn't compiles

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a new in Scala. I created a package object in my code:

```
package mypackage.spark

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import mypackage.spark.SparkContextFunctions

package object spark {
  implicit def toSparkContextFunctions(sc: SparkContext): SparkContextFunctions =
new SparkContextFunctions(sc)
}
```

I expect that when I use **import mypackage.spark._**, I will able to use methods from **SparkContextFunctions** class. This approach works for me, when I use only only one imported package object. But when I add additional import in my code. For example:

```
import mypackage.spark._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

**com.datastax.spark.connector._** doing the same for **org.apache.spark.SparkContext** class. My code stop compile and I have an error that used method is not a member of **SparkContext** class. When I change the order of imports the compiler starts see methods from **mypackage.spark._** and stops see methods from **com.datastax.spark.connector._**

Maybe I missed something? Or Scala doesn't support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use two classes named `SparkContext` at the same time, you can alias them:

```
import my.package.name.{SparkContext => MySparkContext}
import some.other.package.name.{SparkContext => OtherSparkContext}
```

Classes from the same package you can be aliased in the same `import`:

```
import my.package.name.{SparkContext => MySparkContext, SomethingElse => MySomethingElse}
```

You may want to choose better names than `MyXXX` and `OtherXXX`.

Comment: Thank you for answer but this is not answer for my question. Thank you for your advice, i use better names in project i removed package name just for example.

Comment: I was not referring to your code, but to my example, where I used MyXXX and OtherXXX. Based on your description I would say you have a name-clash from the wildcard-imports you use, so if that is not the case you may want to augment the question to make the issue clearer.

Comment: I use this approach: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-add-new-methods-to-existing-classes and add methods in two different package objects and want to use them at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The imports may conflict in two ways: either both use `toSparkContextFunctions` for the implicit conversion name or both provide extension methods with the same name (even if different signature).

If neither is the case, there should be no problem. If one is, change your method names, since you can't change the ones in `com.datastax.spark.connector`.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.